# java.sql.SQLException: Data truncated for column 'version' at row 221651

Tags: mysql, jdbc, sqlexception

When I run a sql using Navicat for MySQL successfully,but failed using java jdbc program.The sql like this:

```
INSERT INTO version_event (app_token, event_id, version) 
SELECT
    a.app_token,
    a.event_name event_id,
    a.version
FROM
    day_custom_event a
LEFT JOIN custom_events b ON a.event_name = b.event_id
WHERE
    a.channel = 'all'
AND a.country = 'all'
AND a.version != 'all'
GROUP BY
    a.app_token,
    a.event_name,
    a.version;"
```

and the table like this:
enter image description here

[image]

and the jdbc program is:

JDBC Program:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here in your table you have set column version datatype varchar(50). That maximum allows 5o characters if you inserting anything whose character length is more than 50 then it will give you Data truncated error in java.

so, as the solution either increase the size from 50 or change the datatype of the column.

Comment: if the length of column version is too short,why the sql could run successfully  with Navicat for MySQL？

Comment: SQL query will execute but it will truncate data after 50th character. refresh the table and check again.

Comment: when I increase the size,it worked.Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the problem occurs when you are trying to save some data that is too long for the column. In this case the value for version column is too long.

This mean that the field is too small to save the data so check the datatype definition of that column and increase it's size if necessary.